# How to sleep/wait within an app without making the UI unresponsive

Tags: visual-c++

I'm developing an app for Windows in Visual C++ which would get inputs from a web API. Some of the API calls require me to request response in some specified time delay and during this time I would like to display a spinner.

I'm all good with the displaying spinner, disabling the buttons etc for the time I need to wait before proceeding to the request, but don't know how to pause the process within the app. Obviously, if I use the `_sleep` function, the app becomes unresposive.

Here's more or less what I need to achieve (pseudo-code)

```
void doSomething()
{
   ui->button1->setEnable(false);
   SendAPIReuqest1();

   while (APIRequest1_success)
   {
      requestAPIRequest1_response();
      //wait 10s if false and retry, this can take up to 5mins
   }

   SendAPIRequest2();
   //wait 30s - here I know I can start the job on my end exactly after 30s

   doSometing2();
   ui->button1->setEnable(true);
}
```

What would be the correct approach to achieve what I need?

Comment: How long of a delay are we talking, milliseconds or seconds range? could be a few options, most likely you'll want to read system time periodically and once a certain amount of time has elapsed check to see if you have a response from the web api. You could also check the response in a separate worker thread

Comment: In general we're talking about dozens of seconds (10-30s), but one of the jobs I send to API can take even up to a couple of minutes (depending on available resources - from a few seconds until even 5 mins), so for this one I would need query for response like every 10 seconds in a loop. Since these times are quite long, I don't want to get the app unresponsive.

Comment: Since these time are fairly long, can you just run your entire ui in a loop and just check for a response once at the end of the loop once everything else is handled? Could just set a flag when you're expecting to receive data, and then check whether the data is received after handling ui components first? Threads do make a more sophisticated ui usually but if you don't need the extra functionality this could be a simple solution.

Comment: Correct, there's no reason to use a dedicated thread here. Just use the post an event to the event loop scheduled for 30 seconds.

Comment: If I recall, "VisualC++" is really CLR/CLI , which is basically a thin wrapper around MFC, isn't it? Is that the UI framework you're using?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Qt, and I've just realized it's impossible to access the UI items from a secondary thread...

Answer (score -1):

You'll most likely just want to poll for a response from the web API, alternatively you can start a secondary thread to check for a response from the web API;

After seeing some minimal code, something similar to this may work.

```
//takes an initial start time, calculates elapsed time, compares  elapsed time to count
bool ready(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>&start, const double& count) {
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end-start;
    if (diff.count() >= count) {
        start = end;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
} 

void doSomething()
{
    static std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start;
    static int state = 0;
    switch(state) {
    case (0):
        ui->button1->setEnable(false);
        SendAPIRequest1();
        if (APIRequest1_success) {
            start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            ++state;
        }
        break;
    case (1):
        if (ready(start, 10.0) && requestAPIRequest1_response()) ++state;
        break;
    case(2):
        SendAPIRequest2();
        start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        ++state;
        break;
    case(3):
        if (ready(start, 30.0)) {
            doSomething2();
            ui->button1->setEnable(true);
            state = 0;
         }
         break;
    }
}
```

This way you can call the function and it will either attempt one of the requests or return to do other tasks.

or with threads it could be as simple as

```
void worker_func(std::promise<bool>&& result) {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    SendAPIRequest1();
    while (!requestAPIRequest1_response()) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s);
    }
    SendAPIRequest2();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(30s);
    doSomething2();
    result.set_value(true);
}

void doSomething() {
    static std::future<bool> finished;
    static bool flag = true;
    if (flag) {
        std::promise<bool> _finished;
        finished = _finished.get_future();
        ui.button1.setEnable(false);
        std::thread worker(worker_func, std::move(_finished));
        flag = false;
    } else if (finished.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready) {
        //finished.get();
        worker.join();
        ui.button1.setEnable(true);
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

This way your main thread can keep running the ui, while the worker thread waits for the web API response, as long as your requests aren't handling any QT ui components I believe this should work.

Edit:

Since I have never used QT and it was never mentioned originally that QT was being used the above answers may or may not be usefull, however it looks like QT has some functions to handle things like this. maybe you can just start and stop a Qtimer

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &foo::update);
timer->start(1000);
```

would run the function `foo::update()` every second, the time interval can be changed accordingly. Here is a reference to [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) and a reference to another class which may be of interest [QTimerEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimerevent.html) not to mention, QT has an entire event handling system [The Event System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint - I'll check it out. Anyway, would I be able to access the UI elements (for instance, to enable back the buttons) from another thread?

Comment: If they're defined globally you'll have no issues, though you will have to take care when accessing the same data between multiple threads to avoid race conditions. if this is something you're interested in, have a look at std::mutex as well.

Comment: By "globally" do you mean it would be enough they belong to the same class, or they have to be global within the whole project? You know, I would just want to enable buttons if I get a reply from the API, so there's no risk other threads would be accessing the same data. Sorry, these are my first steps with C++, so the learning curve is pretty steep...

Comment: It will be like accessing data from any regular function, you can either pass parameters to the function or use global objects visible to the entire project.

Comment: The above would code would still make the app unresponsive, wouldn't it? In general, I would be sending two requests to the API: the first one creates a resource on the cloud and that takes from a couple of seconds to like 5 mins (depending on available resources) - I want to send a query in 10s intervals whether the resource is ready yet; the second one starts an endpoint (this takes up to 30s), so I would call my function to send the quest to the endpoint at least after 30s.

Comment: because I added nothing more than STL functions and objects its a portable solution for multiple operating systems, not just Windows. (a lot of MFC stuff is just wrappers for STL classes anyway, I'd rather post something portable.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, @pseudovella! The first one doesn't solve my problem, as the UI gets unresponsive for the time the `ready` function is running. On the other hand, the second one won't work either, because it turns out Qt UI elements can be accessed only from the main thread... Do you see any other simple solution to achieve what I need?

Comment: the `ready` function is non blocking so I really have no idea how it would render the ui unresponsive. both functions (ready and do something) are 100% non blocking in the first example. either a task will be run or the function will return, there's no spinning at all

Comment: Actually you're right, I haven't removed the sleep function from my code and that's why the UI was unresponsive. Nevertheless, I'm still not sure how should I use this one. If I understand correctly, to go through the switch block, I would need to call the `doSomething` method multiple times, so I would need to schedule that (and sleep) somewhere else in the code.

Comment: a ui is usually just one big loop run over and over again until the user exits, unless perhaps yours just runs once ? but I assumed the main ui to be a loop. you would just need to call the function once within the main loop, in my example i assume that doSomething2() will signal that it has finished, or that the button coming back online would be enough of a singal. however if those dont work, you could just make `doSomething2()` return a bool signaling when all work has completed. Are you just running a bunch of stuff in Serial once?

Comment: I inherited this code (C++, UI in Qt), and I have very vague/no idea about both. Thus, I'm not sure about the main UI loop. From my research it looks like I'd need to use QFutureWatcher or something similar to achieve what I need...